# Compare two files in c; skip lines with specific words

Tags: c

I have to compare two text files.Lines start with `<\cipher>` and `<\mac>` should be ignored in both files. These tags are at the same line in both files. I don't know how to ignore those lines.

1. Have to skip those tags of lines from both files.
2. Compare lines and each characters.
3. Check the end of file/size of each files.

Only no.1 has to be solved and no.2 and no.3 are already solved in this following code.

Example files:

**TextFile 1**

```
<\date> 16th December 2016 
<\name> thiri
<\cipher> a girl
<\age> 22
<\mac> 2316
```

**TextFile 2**

```
<\date> 16th December 2016
<\name> thiri
<\cipher> female
<\age> 22
<\mac> 1234
```

My code is described below:

```
int main (int argc, const char *argv [ ])
{
    //Compare Text- Compare two files in details(but cannot ignore such lines)

    FILE *fpr1, *fpr2;
    int ch1, ch2;
    char fname1[80], fname2[80];

    printf("Enter file-directory:");
    scanf("%s",fname2);

    fpr1 = fopen("/Users/khinthirihtet/Documents/PSKC_Testing/PSKC_Testing/narme.txt", "r");
    fpr2 = fopen(fname2, "r");

    if (fpr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open REFERENCE_FILE in %s", fname1);
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (fpr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open your file in %s to check format", fname2);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((ch1 != EOF) && (ch2 != EOF) && (ch1 == ch2))
        {
            ch1 = getc(fpr1);
            ch2 = getc(fpr2);
        }    
        if (ch1 == ch2)
            printf("Your File is matched.");
        else if (ch1 != ch2)
            printf("Your File is NOT matched,please verify again!");

        fclose(fpr1);
        fclose(fpr2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the example, the `<\cipher>` and `<\mac>` lines occur at the same lines in the two inputs.  Is that guaranteed, or could you have the second file containing, for example, (1) `<\date> 16th December 2016`, 
(2) `<\name> thiri`,
(3) `<\mac> 1234`, (4) `<\cipher> female`, 
(5) `<\age> 22`.  This could also be considered the same as the first file if you ignore the `<\mac>` and `<\cipher>` lines as elements (1), (2), (5) are the values in the same order as the other file.

Comment: Yes, it is sure that, the result should be the same regardless of <\cipher> and <\mac> tags comparison. They are at the same line of both files except with different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than a couple of subtle opportunities for learning in the assignment. The first of which is properly escaping the skip terms so a valid comparison can be made. With that overcome, there are really only two functions necessary to make the comparison: `strncmp` (to check for skip terms), and `strcmp` (to check remaining lines).

In addition to checking the contents of the lines, you will also need to check whether one file is longer (has more lines) than the other. A quick way is to check whether both attempts to read from each file read `EOF` at the same time. If one reaches `EOF` or returns `NULL` before the other, then the files differ as well. (You can't rely on a size check as the contents of skipped lines may vary).

Putting those together in a short example, one approach to making the comparison would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s file1 file2\n", 
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *skip[] = { "<\\cipher>", "<\\mac>" }; /* skip terms       */
    char s1[MAXL] = {0}, s2[MAXL] = {0};        /* lines from files */
    unsigned char differ = 0;                   /* differ flag      */
    size_t skipsz = sizeof skip/sizeof *skip;   /* elements in skip */
    size_t i = 0;   /* general variable */
    FILE *f1, *f2;  /* file pointers    */

    /* open both files or exit */
    if (!((f1 = fopen (argv[1], "r")) && (f2 = fopen (argv[2], "r")))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failure.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read a line from each file */
    for (;;)
    {
        char *p1 = fgets (s1, MAXL, f1);    /* check return of read */
        char *p2 = fgets (s2, MAXL, f2);

        if ((!p1 && p2) || (p1 && !p2)) {
            differ = 1;     /* if one file is longer than the other */
            break;
        }
        else if (!(p1 || p2))
            break;          /* if both return NULL at EOF, break    */

        for (i = 0; i < skipsz; i++)    /* skip if matches skip[i]  */
            if (strncmp (s1, skip[i], strlen (skip[i])) == 0 ||
                strncmp (s2, skip[i], strlen (skip[i])) == 0 )
                goto skipping;          /* yes -- it lives....      */

        if (strcmp (s1, s2)) {          /* compare lines & set flag */
            differ = 1;
            break;
        }
        skipping:;
    }

    fclose (f1);    /* close files */
    fclose (f2);

    if (differ)     /* print results */
        printf ("\n files '%s' and '%s': differ\n\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    else
        printf ("\n files '%s' and '%s': match\n\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmpf1f2 dat/tf1.txt dat/tf2.txt

 files 'dat/tf1.txt' and 'dat/tf2.txt': match
```

**Note:** the initial line size if set with the `MAXL` (maxline) `define`. It can be adjusted as needed. Next, you should also implement test to check that you have read an entire line from both `f1` and `f2` by checking that the line length is less than `MAXL` and if it equals `MAXL`, you will need to validate the last character read is the newline.

**Note2:** on using `goto` -- rarely if ever do it. When it is appropriate? Answer: when you need to break out of (or continue within) multiple loops where `break` or `continue` will not work. Options? Your other option is to set a flag (with outer loop scope) before breaking and test immediately at the end of the current loop block and break again if the flag is set. (`goto` allows you to break across multiple loops -- and you will find it in many of the C library functions -- like `qsort`, etc..)

---

**Testing Skipped Lines Same Length**

You are already comparing whether `<\cipher>` and `<\mac>` occur on the same line by testing the first characters of both `s1` and `s2` are equal to `skip[i]`. To add a test that confirms both skipped lines are the same length, simply test the `strlen` of both `s1` and `s2` following the skip test and set `differ` and break out of the loops if they differ in length. The additional test could look something like the following in the code:

```
    /* read a line from each file */
    for (;;)
    {
        char *p1 = fgets (s1, MAXL, f1);    /* check return of read */
        char *p2 = fgets (s2, MAXL, f2);

        if ((!p1 && p2) || (p1 && !p2)) {
            differ = 1;     /* if one file is longer than the other */
            break;
        }
        else if (!(p1 || p2))
            break;          /* if both return NULL at EOF, break    */

        for (i = 0; i < skipsz; i++)    /* skip if matches skip[i]  */
            if (strncmp (s1, skip[i], strlen (skip[i])) == 0 ||
                strncmp (s2, skip[i], strlen (skip[i])) == 0 ) {
                if (strlen (s1) == strlen (s2))
                    goto skipping;      /* yes -- it lives....      */
                else {
                    differ = 1;
                    goto finish;
                }
            }
        if (strcmp (s1, s2)) {          /* compare lines & set flag */
            differ = 1;
            break;
        }
        skipping:;
    }
    finish:;
```

Comment: The more restriction is that verifying
<cipher>ab12<cipher/> and also <mac> should be existed at the same line of both file and the length of them should be same whether ‘ab12’ in one file or ‘ef23’ in another one.
I declared the static char table[] ={‘a’-‘z’,’0’-‘9’};
I am not sure that is it possible to check the length of values and same lines regardless of comparing values.

Comment: Sure it is. Give me a little bit and I'll add the checks to the answer.

Comment: With the different idea of checking format, kindly request to know if restrictions are as follows. Please check my question again.

Comment: Yes, every one, `<\cipher> or <\max>` line length and same lines in file, file lengths and all other lines. `1,2,3` restrictions are satisfied. Just include all parts of the answer. If you need help putting it all together, let me know and I'll post the whole thing in a single example.

Comment: **Note:** I didn't re-test with any different files.

Comment: Code for matching string between two files work properly and I have already tested. In a question //2. Check file format is modified with more restrictions. It's a different scenario but a bit complex. do u want me to make a new question of it?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it. Otherwise, when others look at this question, none of the other answers will match anymore. I'll look for it.

Comment: thz Mr.Rankin, here is a question of verifying contents of file. Hope u would show a way to solve somehow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155479/compare-2-files-skip-specific-lines-and-put-some-to-new-text-in-c

Comment: Ok I'll have a look. It will be in the morning, sit tight.

Comment: thz for ur appreciation. I am also trying to verify somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little easier if the special words are at the front of each line, but the general solution is the same either way.  Make a function to read a line from a file and return a string.  If the function finds a line with one of the special strings then it completes the reading of the line but then discards that text and restarts reading a line.  Call this function for each of your 2 files and compare the results of those.  Repeat until you've reached the end of one or both files.

Comment: <\ciphers> and </Mac> are not only two tags in a file also. There are 20 tags for each of them and if you would mind, could u give some example?

Comment: I wrote my answer with the idea that you are working on an assignment from a course that you are taking.  I did not write the code for it on purpose. 
I don't understand why more special words changes the general algorithm.  If you get it working and then find that you need to optimize the identification of the special words in your text then I would be happy to help or make suggestions for that, but you aren't at that point yet.

Comment: I would rather buffer the text file and work from the buffer (that is similar to string), but not from file as it is way more slow and hard and limited.