# Verify file format first and then retrieve required information in C

Tags: c

```
<School>
      </SchoolName>latha2  //skip, but keep
</School>

<Student>
   <Team>power  //skip,but keep
   <StudentNo>1 //skip
       <Sport>
            <StartDate>16122016</StartDate> //*skip(May or maynot contained)
            <SportType>All 
            <ExpiryDate>16122020</EndDate> //*skip (May or maynot contained)
       </Sport>

 <Personal> 
   <phone>50855466 //skip,but keep
   <rollno>6 //skip,but keep
 </Personal>
 <hobby>  //skip
</Student>
```

Note: There are 4 `<Student>` tags.

- Assume that File1 is fixed and File2 is input-file.
  In File 1,one school with 4 students. In File 2,there are many schools but have to check  with File-1 format repeatedly according to the number of schools it has. Above is an example of File1.

"Scenario"
- There are 4 package of "Student" tags in one school. In each tags, the value of   "Team" are repeated.

"Questions with restrictions"

1. From File 1,"Sport" Tag, "StartDate" and "ExpiryDate" are defined but they may not be contained in every "School" from File2.

   - If they are defined, how to verify that they should be at the correct line?.
   - How to verify that format is right even they are not defined in some schools of File2?
2. Some lines are skipped when 2 files are compared but some lines need to be collected form File2 to write a new txt even they are skipped. From File2, "SchoolName", "Team","phone" and "roll no" are retrieved and write txt altogether line by line.
   ****Important, retrieve "Team" once from one "School". Because it is repeated 4 times in four "Student" from same "School".

   - How to retrieve only SchoolName,Team,Phone,RollNo among the skipped lines?
   - How to retrieve only Team in writing new textfile even it is duplicated in students under one school?

Two things to be done. 1. Match File Format 2.New Text with specific values

"Example of new text"

```
 latha2   // SchoolName    
 power    // Team
 5035546  // phone  - student1
 6        // rollno - student1
 5089973  // phone  - student2
 5        // rollno - student2
 5402734  // phone  - student3
 1        // rollno - student3
 8540345  // phone  - student4
 2        // rollno - student4
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You will need to post `file1` or does it just contain the same as `file2` without `<StartDate>` and `<ExpiryDate>`?

Comment: @Wimmel it is a continuation from a prior post with a second part to his original question. He needs to know how to compare and skip varying tagged lines. The original was [**Skip line with specific words compare two files in c**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/50320191?noredirect=1)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, The format shown above is file1. In file1, <SchoolName> latha2 has <StartDate> and <ExpiryDate> of Sport. In file2, there are many school names and some school doesn't have them but some have. Let's consider that no record of date for sport in some schools.

Comment: Basically simple tasks such as 'test if a line in File1 is anywhere in File2', 'test a line against a format', and 'retrieve a Team' are *not done easily with C*. You may want to use something like a database instead. Or, since this appears to be XML, look in to XSLT.

Comment: @Jongware . File1 is assumed as standard format. It cannot be tested against a format. Somehow you are right, it could also be XML but database will not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared to the earlier question, this one isn't about comparing files for differences with certain exceptions. Here you have a `format` file that provides the valid tags and order, and then a `data` file that contains the tags with data. So rather than comparing for differences, you are reading the first to obtain the expected/valid tags, then reading/processing the second to obtain the wanted information.

Below, I also have the code check that the tags in the file appear in the correct order. You can loosen that restriction if you don't need it. Another bit of logic skips lines less that `3` chars (a valid tag has **at least** `3` (e.g. `<t>`)).

The formatting of the output is very simple and you can improve it as needed. I had no data file to work with, so I used the information you provided and created one by duplicating your file above 3-times in a separate file. Look over the code. As other have mentioned, parsing XML in C, while a great assignment, is rarely done in practice because other tools provide readily available tools for handling the schemas. Let me know if you have any questions. This will provide you with one approach to handling this type of information:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXL 128

char *gettag (char *s, char *t);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s file1 file2\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char s1[MAXL] = {0};                        /* line buffer      */
    char *tags[MAXL] = {0};                     /* file 1 tags      */
    char *retr[] = { "<Team>", "<phone>",       /* skip/print terms */
                    "<rollno>" };
    char *retr1[] = { "</SchoolName>",          /* skip/print once  */
                    "<Team>" };
    char *skip[] = { "<StudentNo>","<hobby>" }; /* skip terms       */
    char *opt[]  = { "<StartDate>",             /* optional tags    */
                    "<ExpiryDate>"};
    size_t retrsz = sizeof retr/sizeof *retr;   /* elements in retr */
    size_t retr1sz = sizeof retr1/sizeof *retr1;/* elements in retr1*/
    size_t skipsz = sizeof skip/sizeof *skip;   /* elements in skip */
    size_t optsz = sizeof opt/sizeof *opt;      /* elements in opt  */
    size_t tidx = 0;                            /* tags indes       */
    size_t idx = 0;                             /* general index    */
    size_t i = 0;                               /* general variable */
    FILE *f1, *f2;                              /* file pointers    */
    unsigned char retvd[retr1sz];               /* retr1 flag       */
    unsigned char tagok = 0;                    /* tag OK flag      */

    /* initialize retr1 VLA values */
    for (i = 0; i < retr1sz; i++)
        retvd[i] = 0;

    /* open both files or exit */
    if (!((f1 = fopen (argv[1], "r")) && (f2 = fopen (argv[2], "r")))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failure.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read lines from format file1, create tags array */
    while (fgets (s1, MAXL, f1)) 
    {
        size_t len = strlen (s1);
        while (len && (s1[len-1] == '\n' || s1[len-1] == '\r'))
            s1[--len] = 0;      /* strip newline or carriage return */

        if (len < 3)            /* skip blank, 3 char for valid tag */
            continue;

        char *tmp = NULL;
        if ((tmp = gettag (s1, NULL)) == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: tag not found in '%s'", s1);
            return 1;
        }
        tags[tidx++] = tmp;
    }

    fclose (f1);    /* close file1 */

    /* read each line in file2 */
    while (fgets (s1, MAXL, f2))
    {
        char tag[MAXL] = {0};
        size_t len = strlen (s1);

        while (len && (s1[len-1] == '\n' || s1[len-1] == '\r'))
            s1[--len] = 0;      /* strip newline or carriage return */

        if (len < 3)            /* skip blank or lines < 3 chars    */
            goto skipping;

        gettag (s1, tag);
        /* verify that current tag is a valid tag from format file  */
        if (strncmp (tag, tags[idx], strlen (tags[idx])) != 0) {
            tagok = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < tidx; i++) {
                if (strncmp (tag, tags[i], strlen (tags[i])) == 0) {
                    tagok = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!tagok) {
                fprintf (stderr, "warning: invalid tag '%s', skipping.\n", tag);
                goto skipping;  /* or handle as desired (e.g. exit) */
            }
        }

        /* check if tag is retr1 and not retvd, if so skip/print    */
        for (i = 0; i < retr1sz; i++)
            if (strncmp (tag, retr1[i], strlen (retr1[i])) == 0) {
                if (!retvd[i]) {        /* print line  skipped      */
                    char *p = strchr (s1, '>'); /* print data       */
                    printf ("%s\n", (p + 1));
                    retvd[i] = 1;       /* set flag to skip next    */
                }
                goto incriment;         /* yes -- it lives....      */
            }

        /* check if tag is a known retr tag, if so skip/print       */
        for (i = 0; i < retrsz; i++)    /* skip if matches skip[i]  */
            if (strncmp (tag, retr[i], strlen (retr[i])) == 0) {
                char *p = strchr (s1, '>');
                printf ("%s\n", (p + 1));      /* print data       */
                goto incriment;
            }

        /* check if tag is a known skip tag, if so skip/print       */
        for (i = 0; i < skipsz; i++)    /* skip if matches skip[i]  */
            if (strncmp (tag, skip[i], strlen (skip[i])) == 0)
                goto incriment;

        /* check if tag matches optional tag, if so skip */
        for (i = 0; i < optsz; i++) {
            if (strncmp (tag, opt[i], strlen (opt[i]) == 0))
                goto incriment;
        }

        incriment:;

        idx++;                  /* increment index  */
        if (idx == tidx)        /* reset if tagsz   */
            idx = 0;

        skipping:;
    }

    fclose (f2);                /* xlose file2      */

    for (i = 0; i < tidx; i++)  /* free tags memory */
        free (tags[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* extract <tag> from s.
* if 't' is NULL, memory is allocated sufficient to hold <tag> + 1
* characters, else <tag> is copied to 't' without allocations.
* On success, the address of 't' is returned, NULL otherwise 
*/
char *gettag (char *s, char *t)
{
    if (!s) return NULL;            /* test valid string        */

    char *p = strchr (s, '>');      /* find first '>' in s      */
    if (!p) return NULL;            /* if no '>', return NULL   */

    size_t len = strlen (s);
    unsigned char nt = 0;
    int tmpc = 0;

    if (len > (size_t)(p - s) + 1) {/* if chars after '>'       */
        tmpc = *(p + 1);            /* save char before term    */
        *(p + 1) = 0;               /* null-terminate at '>'    */
        nt = 1;                     /* set null-terminated flag */
    }

    char *sp = s;
    while (sp < p && *sp != '<')    /* trim space before '<'    */
        sp++;

    if (!t)
        t = strdup (sp);            /* allocate/copy to t       */
    else
        strncpy (t, sp, len + 1);   /* copy w/terminator        */

    if (nt)                         /* if null-terminated       */
        *(p + 1) = tmpc;            /* restore '>' character    */

    return t;
}
```

**File1 - format (list tags)**

```
$ cat dat/student_format.txt
<School>
      </SchoolName>latha2  //skip, but keep
</School>
<Student>
   <Team>power  //skip,but keep
   <StudentNo>1 //skip
       <Sport>
            <StartDate>16122016</StartDate> //*skip(May or maynot contained)
            <SportType>All
            <ExpiryDate>16122020</EndDate> //*skip (May or maynot contained)
       </Sport>

 <Personal>
   <phone>50855466 //skip,but keep
   <rollno>6 //skip,but keep
 </Personal>
 <hobby>  //skip
</Student>
```

**File1 - data file (same as above 3 times)**

```
$ cat dat/student_file.txt
<School>
      </SchoolName>latha2
</School>

<Student>
   <Team>power
   <StudentNo>1
       <Sport>
            <StartDate>16122016</StartDate>
            <SportType>All
            <ExpiryDate>16122020</EndDate>
       </Sport>

 <Personal>
   <phone>50855466
   <rollno>6
 </Personal>
 <hobby>
</Student>
<School>
      </SchoolName>latha2
</School>

<Student>
   <Team>power
   <StudentNo>1
       <Sport>
            <StartDate>16122016</StartDate>
            <SportType>All
            <ExpiryDate>16122020</EndDate>
       </Sport>

 <Personal>
   <phone>50855466
   <rollno>6
 </Personal>
 <hobby>
</Student>
<School>
      </SchoolName>latha2
</School>

<Student>
   <Team>power
   <StudentNo>1
       <Sport>
            <StartDate>16122016</StartDate>
            <SportType>All
            <ExpiryDate>16122020</EndDate>
       </Sport>

 <Personal>
   <phone>50855466
   <rollno>6
 </Personal>
 <hobby>
</Student>
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmpf1f2_2 dat/student_format.txt dat/student_file.txt
latha2
power
50855466
6
50855466
6
50855466
6
```

Comment: Each <Student> package's format from File 2 match with <Student> package's format from File1. Now, tags from file 2 can be deleted and it's still works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: Beside this, I would also want to learn not only C program but also logics. Hope you could recommend good ideas. thanks.

Comment: Error must be shown when tags from File 2 are not identical with File1. Even I delete <Student>,<phone> and so on from File 2, there is no warning and also print out results from tags remained.

Comment: Moreover, “Team” is repeated among 4 students. That’s why printed once. In File2, there are different teams for 4 students. And number of <student> from file2 should be divided by 4. Are those things can be verified with strictly define?

Comment: Could u let me know how could it do plz ?

Comment: The quickest way to really learn C is to -- SLOW DOWN. C is an `exact` language, every part of each line matters. (there is no 'close enough'). This is the mistake all new C programmers make. C's power stems from the low-level control it provides over the machine. You are basically just managing memory (or pointers to memory). All variables and pointers are simply values in memory or the address to a location in memory. Learn that. The examples I provided contain great examples, they just cover a LOT. Take them piece by piece. It just takes time, there is no magic. You will get there.

Comment: What prints once and is skipped is controlled by the code under the comment `check if tag is retr1 and not retvd, if so skip/print` Look at what each line does. If you have `teams` and you now want to print for each time, you need to move `"<Team>"` from the `retr1` array to the `retr` array so it is printed each time the tag is found. Really, these are great examples for learning (A LOT). That's why I took the time to do them for you. Take it **line-by-line** and discover what is happening. Look up each function. When you get stuck -- ask, I'm happy to help, but I can't learn for you.

Comment: Thanks for yr concern. Actually,I have already moved it to retr. It prints out results, but 4 teams are duplicated among 4 students, but let me figure out and try.